# Is there any way to show artifacts from GCP Artifact Registry as Jenkins build parameter

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform

**The inputs**:

- Jenkins CI/CD pipeline
- GCP Artifacts Registry with Docker images

**What to need**:
Configure Jenkins job to have a parameter where the user will select a Docker image from GCP Artifact Registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Groovy Script to access the google cloud API and list the docker images inside a build parameter. For example I generate some pipelines using Jenkins JobDSL. The config looks like this:

```
job('cicd-job'){
   parameters {
    activeChoiceParam("Google Artifact Docker Image") {
        choiceType("SINGLE_SELECT")
        description("Select the Docker Image you want to use")
        groovyScript {
            fallbackScript('return["error"]')
            script("""
               def result = USING SOME LIBRARY OR USE THE HTTP CLIENT TO CONNECT TO THE GOOGLE API AND LOAD/LIST THE IMAGES.
               return result""")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a blog post that describes a similar scenario but using DockerHub https://kublr.com/blog/advanced-jenkins-groovy-scripting-for-live-fetching-of-docker-images/